# Is the phrase "You are requested" polite or rude?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

My supervisor and I wrote a research paper to be sent to journal for review. My supervisor wrote the cover letter of the paper as

> Dear Editor in Chief
>
> You are requested to review the paper "Title of the paper"....
>
> Thanks

This cover letter is from the authors of the research paper (authors are my supervisor and I) to the Editor in chief of the journal requesting for our paper to be reviewed.
To me, it seems a very impolite way of beginning a cover letter to be written to an Editor in chief who is much higher in rank and position, on the other hand, we are mere authors of the paper. But he didn't agree to it. Does it seems impolite, or is the usage of phrase "You are requested" fine and polite?

Comment: Is it the first time this editor has reviewed a paper for your supervisor? If this is just a routine request for something he has done many times before, it's probably fine. A more formal request would be appropriate if it's the first time.

Comment: I think, the question is misunderstood. I and my supervisor have written a research paper to be submitted for a journal. Every research paper requires a cover letter to be written to the editor in chief, in which we give the reasons why our paper should be sent for review. It is in that context. This cover letter is from the authors of the paper to Editor in Chief of the journal

Comment: The expression comes from above not from below. An authority may use the expression "you are requested" addressing someone below. In the context, it is inappropriate and so may even sound rude. HTH.

Comment: As a request for advice upon the tone of writing, especially academic writing, rather than on the nuts and bolts of the English language, this question properly belongs on the Writers SE site. I'll add :) to show that this is in no way intended to appear rude. // 'To whom it may concern' shocked me the first time I came across it on a reference. But it's actually bog-standard non-affrontary.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand your question, I only asked whether or not you had sent papers to this particular editor before.

Comment: @KateBunting: The cover letter goes to an editor in chief, who decides whether to send our paper for review or not. We do not directly email him, however, it goes via online submission system, where we are required to attach the cover letter along with our paper. If the editor in chief finds our paper suitable, he sends it to the reviewers for comments

Comment: Dealing with the word request - this is not inherently rude. A request is optional. If you had written '*demanded*', that would be **very rude**. However, '***You** are requested to*' seems very authoritarian and less polite than '*We request that you*' as a native BrE speaker. I think the way it is written in the OP is not as polite as it could be, but may well be the standard for submitting to journals.

Comment: I think any possible rudeness comes from the 'You'. If it started 'We request that you..' it would be much gentler. As it is, it's not giving the editor an option 'You ARE requested..' to which some might react 'Oh am I now? We'll see about that'. But I wouldn't worry about that too much. These days most people are used to and recognise different flavours of English. Indeed, this phrase is one tell-tale.

Comment: To me it sounds overly formal, similar to the way invitations to fancy events might say "You are invited to ..."

Comment: Cross-posted on https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/48516/is-the-phrase-you-are-requested-polite-or-rude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with you that, "You are requested" sounds inappropriate.

The internet has examples, such as:

https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/authorandreviewertutorials/submitting-to-a-journal-and-peer-review/cover-letters/10285574

Dear Editor-in-Chief,
I am sending you our manuscript entitled “Large Scale Analysis of Cell Cycle Regulators in bladder cancer” by Researcher et al. We would like to have the manuscript considered for publication in....

https://wordvice.com/journal-submission-cover-letter/

e.g., I am writing to submit our manuscript entitled, “X Marks the Spot” for consideration as an Awesome Science Journal research article. We examined the efficacy of using X factors as indicators for depression in Y subjects in Z regions thro

Comment: First Rule of Persuasive Letter Writing: do **not** start the letter with the word "I".  It's very self-centered.

Comment: "The reason your cover letter should be in first person is simple. This document is a letter, which means you write directly to the employer. Your resume should not be in first person, so you should take this opportunity to sell yourself as much as you can. ... Yes, you can (and should) write a cover letter in first person.Aug 8, 2018" No good?

Comment: Nothing you wrote in that comment contradicts what I wrote.  (It's perfectly possible to write a first person letter without starting with "I".  Really.  It just takes a little thought.)

Comment: First sentence "I" is all over the net. See here, about a third of the way down. https://www.thebalancecareers.com/cover-letter-opening-sentences-examples-2061030 - Plus a seasoned HR person gave examples of her chosen best openings, and 2 began with "I". The 3rd with "My". Dunno, but why jump thru hoops that aren't necessary and concentrate on the meat of the letter.

Comment: You're misreading me. I wrote "do not start **the letter**.  I did **not** write, "Never start a sentence."  As for what "a seasoned HR person" thinks... I've been employed in Big Business long enough to have a deep and unwavering disdain for the intellectual capacities of HR personnel.

Comment: Ok. Found one that states another viewpoint:  "The point? When you write a cover letter, take the focus off yourself and place it on the person and company you're writing to."  Goes on to say to keep "I" and "my" under control.

Comment: "take the focus off yourself and place it on the person and company you're writing to."  Exactly.  Persuade *them* to hire you.  Appeal to their self-interest.  That's because **starting with** "I" puts the focus on yourself.

Comment: Thanks for standing your ground until I began questioning the 'majority results'. Better search terms are yielding better results. :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't come across as polite or impolite, just odd. "You are requested to review" is unnecessarily passive voice, and implies that someone other than the author of the letter is requesting the review. If I received that letter, I wouldn’t be offended, but probably just amused by the awkwardness of that sentence.

Also, I don't believe it's true that the "Editor in chief... is much higher in rank and position, on the other hand, we are mere authors of the paper". I'm not sure why you're putting him/her on such a pedestal. This is a person in a completely different line of work than you or your supervisor, or at least he/she is functioning in a completely different capacity than you or your supervisor. Also, you're creating content for that journal - without you there'd be nothing to review or publish.

I think a better point-of-view would be to think of the editor as someone who has very limited time, but could also be excited about what you've done, and is interested in publishing high-quality work. Just be direct and polite (see bolded statement in my "letter" below).

Also, I assume you've left some text out of your question, but just to cover all bases, cover letters have common elements:

1. The title of the work.
2. What's great about the work.
3. Why the work is perfect for the journal.
4. Call to action - ask the editor to consider it for publication.

In [this example](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/authorandreviewertutorials/submitting-to-a-journal-and-peer-review/cover-letters/10285574), the author then asks the editor to be notified of the decision when it is made. Google for other examples, but most have these elements. Here's a similar construction that I wrote:

> Dear Editor in Chief,
>
> In the attached paper ([paper title]), we discovered [thing the paper describes]. We believe this is very exciting development in the field of [field]. This work is consistent with the aim an scope of [journal you're submitting to] and would be of general interest to your readership. **We would like you to consider this manuscript for publication in [journal you're submitting to].**
>
> Thanks